# Downloaded exe file has 0 bytes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to learn VB.NET. I want to download a `file.exe` on my desktop and execute it. I wrote this code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim mani As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop 
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("www.example.com/file.exe", mani & "\mani.exe")
        Process.Start(mani & "\mani.exe")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I start the application, it downloads a file to my desktop named `mani.exe`. The original file is 400kb and the downloaded file is 0kb and the file is corrupted.

When I download the file using my browser, it works perfectly and has the right size.

This is the output of the debug:

```
The thread 0x754 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x748 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x15b8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x128c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'Download and Execute.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Download and Execute.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\T0X\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Download and Execute\Download and Execute\bin\Debug\Download and Execute.exe'. Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over property
'Download_and_Execute.My.MyProject.get_Application'.  To step into properties, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
'Download and Execute.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Download and Execute.vshost.exe): Loaded 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Download and Execute.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Download and Execute.vshost.exe): Loaded 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
The program '[7124] Download and Execute.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
The program '[7124] Download and Execute.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: If you download the file using a browser (not from your application) does it have the correct size and does it start?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is an exception thrown? Did you try using the `ShowUI` parameter? [How to: Download a File in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1say4ws7(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Try putting the code in a button click event handler instead.

Comment: i added the code in a button click event handler and the same thing , the download file still 0kb

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the function [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)?

There is this note about [Network.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127875.aspx):

> The DownloadFile method does not send optional HTTP headers.
>   Some servers may return 500 (Internal Server Error) if the optional
>   user agent header is missing. To send optional headers, you must
>   construct a request using the WebClient class.